# rotate text node not move to right target

Tags: d3.js

Below demo try to rotate the text node, it should located at the side of each node but actually far away from the nodes.

```js
demo()

function demo() {
    var r = 5
    var color = 'steelblue'
    
    var width = 800
    var height = 600
    var margin = {top: 20, left: 50,right: 10, bottom: 50}
    var gwidth = width + margin.left + margin.right
    var gheight = height + margin.top + margin.bottom;

    const data = `
AAAA,BBB,CCC,DDDD,EEEEE,X,y,z,u,v,w
BBB,FFFF,GGGGG,HHHHH
DDDD,IIII,JJJJ,KKKK,LLL
`

    var nodes = []
    var links = []
    var dx = 20
    var dy = 20
    var x = 0
    var y = 0
    var alpha = Math.PI/180*70
    var parent = null
    data.trim().split("\n").forEach((line,i) => {
        line.split(",").forEach((elem,j)=> {
            if (elem == "") return
            var m = nodes.find(d => d.name == elem)
            if (m == undefined) {
                var node = {name:elem,x:x,y:y,parent:parent}
                nodes.push(node)
                parent = node
                x += dx
            }else {
                x = m.x + y*Math.cos(alpha)/Math.sin(alpha)                
                parent = m
            }
        })
        y += dy        
    })
    
    var xmin = d3.min(nodes,d => d.x)
    var xmax = d3.max(nodes,d => d.x)
    var ymin = d3.min(nodes,d => d.y)
    var ymax = d3.max(nodes,d => d.y)

    var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .range([0,width])
        .domain([xmin-10,xmax+10])
    
    var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .range([height,0])
        .domain([ymin-10,ymax+10])

    var svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", gwidth)
        .attr("height", gheight)
        .style('border','1px solid red')
    
    var g = svg.append("g")
        .attr('transform',`translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);

    var xaxis = g.append("g")
        .attr("transform",`translate(0,${height})`)
        .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale)
              .tickFormat((d,i) => null)//i==0 ?  null:d)
              .tickSize(0)
             );
    
    var yaxis = g.append("g")
        .attr("transform", `translate(0,0)`)        
        .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale)
              .tickFormat((d,i) => null)//i==0 ?  null:d)
              .tickSize(0)
             );

    [xaxis,yaxis].forEach((d) => d.call(g => g.select(".domain").remove()))
    
    
    var node = g.selectAll('.point')
        .data(nodes)
        .join('circle')
        .attr('class','point')
        .attr('cx',d => xScale(d.x))
        .attr('cy',d => {
            return yScale(d.y)
        })
        .attr('r',r)
        .attr('stroke',color)
        .attr('fill',color)

    var txt = g.selectAll('.txt')
        .data(nodes)
        .join('text')
        .text(d => d.name)
        .attr('class','txt')
        .attr('stroke','black')
        .attr('font-size',40)
        .attr('text-anchor','end')
        .attr('dy',(d,i) => {
            if (d.y == 0) return '.3em'
            else return '-.3em'
        })
        .attr('transform', (d,i) => {
            alpha = 30
            if (d.y == 0) {
                alpha = -30
            }
            return `translate(${xScale(d.x)},${yScale(d.y)})rotate(${alpha})`
        })
    
    function drawlink(d) {
        if (d.parent == null) return ""
        var ax = xScale(d.parent.x)
        var ay = yScale(d.parent.y)
        var bx = xScale(d.x)
        var by = yScale(d.y)
        var path = ['M',ax,ay,'L',bx,by]
        return path.join(' ')
    }

    var links = g.selectAll('.link')
        .data(nodes)
        .join('path')
        .attr('class','link')
        .attr('d',drawlink)
        .attr('stroke',color)
        .attr('stroke-width',r)
    
    return    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3@7.0.4/dist/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've already applied a `text-anchor` attribute to the `<text>` elements for right alignment you can add a **right padding via  [`dx`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/dx)** attribute to prevent the text elements to "bump into" their reference points.

```js
demo();

function demo() {
  var r = 5;
  var color = "steelblue";

  var width = 800;
  var height = 600;
  var margin = { top: 20, left: 50, right: 10, bottom: 50 };
  var gwidth = width + margin.left + margin.right;
  var gheight = height + margin.top + margin.bottom;

  const data = `
AAAA,BBB,CCC,DDDD,EEEEE,X,y,z,u,v,w
BBB,FFFF,GGGGG,HHHHH
DDDD,IIII,JJJJ,KKKK,LLL
`;

  var nodes = [];
  var links = [];
  var dx = 20;
  var dy = 20;
  var x = 0;
  var y = 0;
  var alpha = (Math.PI / 180) * 70;
  var parent = null;
  data
    .trim()
    .split("\n")
    .forEach((line, i) => {
      line.split(",").forEach((elem, j) => {
        if (elem == "") return;
        var m = nodes.find((d) => d.name == elem);
        if (m == undefined) {
          var node = { name: elem, x: x, y: y, parent: parent };
          nodes.push(node);
          parent = node;
          x += dx;
        } else {
          x = m.x + (y * Math.cos(alpha)) / Math.sin(alpha);
          parent = m;
        }
      });
      y += dy;
    });

  var xmin = d3.min(nodes, (d) => d.x);
  var xmax = d3.max(nodes, (d) => d.x);
  var ymin = d3.min(nodes, (d) => d.y);
  var ymax = d3.max(nodes, (d) => d.y);

  var xScale = d3
    .scaleLinear()
    .range([0, width])
    .domain([xmin - 10, xmax + 10]);

  var yScale = d3
    .scaleLinear()
    .range([height, 0])
    .domain([ymin - 10, ymax + 10]);

  var svg = d3
    .select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", gwidth)
    .attr("height", gheight)
    .style("border", "1px solid red");

  var g = svg
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);

  var xaxis = g
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height})`)
    .call(
      d3
        .axisBottom(xScale)
        .tickFormat((d, i) => null) //i==0 ?  null:d)
        .tickSize(0)
    );

  var yaxis = g
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", `translate(0,0)`)
    .call(
      d3
        .axisLeft(yScale)
        .tickFormat((d, i) => null) //i==0 ?  null:d)
        .tickSize(0)
    );

  [xaxis, yaxis].forEach((d) => d.call((g) => g.select(".domain").remove()));

  var node = g
    .selectAll(".point")
    .data(nodes)
    .join("circle")
    .attr("class", "point")
    .attr("cx", (d) => xScale(d.x))
    .attr("cy", (d) => {
      return yScale(d.y);
    })
    .attr("r", r)
    .attr("stroke", color)
    .attr("fill", color);

  var txt = g
    .selectAll(".txt")
    .data(nodes)
    .join("text")
    .text((d) => d.name)
    .attr("class", "txt")
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("font-size", 40)
    .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("dy", (d, i) => {
      if (d.y == 0) {
        return "0.6em";
      } else {
        return "-.1em";
      }
    })

    .attr("dx", (d, i) => {
      if (d.y !== 0) {
        return "-0.3em";
      } else {
        return "-0.3em";
      }
    })

    .attr("transform", (d, i) => {
      alpha = 30;
      if (d.y == 0) {
        alpha = -30;
      }
      return `translate(${xScale(d.x)},${yScale(d.y)})rotate(${alpha})`;
    });

  function drawlink(d) {
    if (d.parent == null) return "";
    var ax = xScale(d.parent.x);
    var ay = yScale(d.parent.y);
    var bx = xScale(d.x);
    var by = yScale(d.y);
    var path = ["M", ax, ay, "L", bx, by];
    return path.join(" ");
  }

  var links = g
    .selectAll(".link")
    .data(nodes)
    .join("path")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("d", drawlink)
    .attr("stroke", color)
    .attr("stroke-width", r);

  return;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3@7.0.4/dist/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Just tweak the conditional x/y offsets to get the desired output.